# PHP Regular Expression with IPv4

Tags: php, regex

I have problems figuring out a regular expression on this pattern

```
oSevenDigits-TwoDigits-aValidIPv4Adress
```

I tried

```
$_regex = "/(o[0-9]{7})-[0-9]{2}-^((2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9])?\d|25[0-5])(\.(?1)){3}\z/";
```

but it seems to be wrong in multiple ways...

Comment: "A valid IPv4 address" is a very annoying and complicated regex to get right. In practice it makes more sense to match `\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}` and then separately validate the address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
$_regex = '/^\d{7}\-\d{2}\-((2([0-5]{2}\.)|1[0-9]{2}\.)|([1-9]{1,2})\.){3}((2[0-5]{2})|(1[0-9]){2}|[0-9])$/';
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have line start `^` in the middle of regex here:

```
$_regex = "/(o[0-9]{7})-[0-9]{2}-^((2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9])?\d|25[0-5])(\.(?1)){3}\z/";
```

Change this to:

```
$_regex = "/(o[0-9]{7})-[0-9]{2}-((2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9])?\d|25[0-5])(\.(?1)){3}/";
```